# Sign in to organization's SharePoint server failed to SharePoint Mobile App

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've set up SharePoint 2019 on-prem and have a few sites; I've also set up SSL. 
 I logged in SharePoint mobile application the first time it asks the server url and credential .but as I login to the app, I'm prompted to log in again. then, it doesn't accept my credential.

I can open both http://portal{domain}. and https://portal.{domain} in browser from my mobile.

Here is more detailed images.

I also send a snapshot of my authentication setting in Central admin which is claime-based and IIS. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have similar problem with you. My app is prompting me "There's no network connection" while I am sure I have hahahha....

Comment: Is it an IOS, Android or Windows OS in your Mobile ?

Comment: Mine is IOS , I've tested Android. the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure SSL, make sure you don’t use self-signed certificates. The SharePoint mobile app can't use self-signed certificates, or those issued by an in-house Certificate Authority (CA).

Reference: [Supporting the SharePoint mobile apps online and on-premises](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/supporting-the-sharepoint-mobile-apps-online-and-on-premises#common-messages-received-by-users)